# Как пометить НЕ прочитанное письмо как прочитанное c# MailKit imap

Tags: c#, winforms, imap, mailkit

основной кусок кода, выполняющий получением писем и дальнейшей укладкой в лист.

```
            client.GetFolder("***").Open(MailKit.FolderAccess.ReadOnly);

            var uids = client.GetFolder("***").Search(SearchQuery.NotSeen);

            var messages = client.GetFolder("***").Fetch(uids, MessageSummaryItems.Envelope | MessageSummaryItems.BodyStructure);

            if (messages != null && messages.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var msg in messages)
                {
                    var body = (TextPart)client.GetFolder("***").GetBodyPart(msg.UniqueId, msg.BodyParts.First());
                    var date = msg.Date;
                    if (date.Date == dateTimePicker1.Value.Date)
                    {
                        list.Add(new MailListItem
                        {
                            msgInList = msg, // тут я в лист вытаскиваю само сообщение (хз зачем)
                            uid = msg.UniqueId.Id.ToString(),
                            From = msg.Envelope.From.ToString(),
                            Date = date,
                            Subject = msg.Envelope.Subject,
                            Body = body.Text,
                            Button = "Открыть письмо",
                            Download = false
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

существует метод SetFlags. Пихаем в него "msg.Index", устанавливаем "Seen".

```
client.GetFolder("***").SetFlags(Convert.ToInt32(uid), MessageFlags.Seen, false);
```

при этом папка должны быть открыта в режиме "ReadWrite".

```
client.GetFolder("***").Open(MailKit.FolderAccess.ReadWrite);
```